# How to focus on current working tab after close popwindow in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

How can I focus on my current working tab after close a pop window?

I have tried various commands but I didn't get the right answer yet. 
I have tried `focus`, `focusandwait` commands but they are not working. Also tried `SelectWindow` command but no success . How can I find my window title?

Comment: After closing the window, what is the line of code you are using? What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: @Saad Saghir, What do you mean by **focus on current window** Selenium IDE will auto move the focus on the current window after closing the popup. so you can continue further action on that current window without taking headache about focus. Can you explain your use cases in details if you are facing really an issue So we will be able to help you out.

Comment: my problem is I am working on an attendance form when I raise the penalty for attendance popup window open and I fill this form after completion when selenium close the popup window after closing focus is not getting back to my current working tab

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
//close popup
driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
```

Comment: I want Answer for Selenium IDE.